# if href=url change class for active state on menu

Tags: jquery, url, navigation

im trying to make an active state with jquery...

heres my code that isn't working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('ul#menuHov a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass("menuHov"); 
});
</script>
```

and the menu...

```
<ul id="menuHov">
    <li style="width:128px"><a href="" ><span>SHOP<br/>SHOP</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:193px"><a href="/collections" ><span>COLLECTIONS<br/>COLLECTIONS</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:147px"><a href="/about-local-celebrity"><span>ABOUT<br/>ABOUT</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:186px"><a href="/stockists" ><span>STOCKISTS<br/>STOCKISTS</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:146px"><a href="/press" ><span>PRESS<br/>PRESS</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:128px"><a href="/category/blog" ><span>BLOG<br/>BLOG</span></a></li>
    <li style="width:70px"><a href="/contact" ><span>CONTACT<br/>CONTACT</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the class i want as active state...

```
.menuHov {color:#fae349}
```

Comment: Have you done a `console.log` to see what value `window.location.pathname` is giving you?

Comment: it was working b4 but i had it do a .css('color', '#whatev') instead of the class... bt i need it to do a class

Comment: @Alex - Well I would use Firebug and `console.log` out the `jQuery('ul#menuHov a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]')`, as well as, `window.location.pathname` to make sure you are selecting what you want. If that is correct, then maybe try applying it the `li` instead of the `a`?

Comment: @Alex - Looks like `.addClass` is fine, according to the jsFiddle.  It's got to be the difference between your URL not matching up to the `window.location.pathname`, as I suspected originally.

Comment: @Alex see my comment to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JYc8g/ (click run if u don't see it work right away)

make sure the path is correct, use the firebug or chrome console to check what `window.location.pathname` is on the page you want

**UPDATE**

seems to be a css issue change line 95 of user.css to:

```
#headerMenu ul li a:hover, a.menuHov {
   color: #00AEEF !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any color change in your links in FF4 or Chrome 10, so how is it working for you, exactly?

Comment: i saw it change, the 2nd links (im using chrome) they changed to yellowish

Comment: collections links changed when u run run

Comment: @Neal - Yea, I just found that out.  First url is /maniator/JYc8g/show/ and doesn't match, but second is /_display/ and matches.

Comment: lol yes ^_^. i had to use `console.log(window.location.pathname)` to find out what to use

Comment: @Neal - exactly what I was doing, yea lol, and then when I clicked run I saw the url change and the color light up and was like, oh, there it is.

Comment: @Alex ur code is working fine: `<a href="/collections" class="menuHov"><span>COLLECTIONS<br>COLLECTIONS</span></a>` that is right from inspect elemet on ur page. its that `.menuHov` is being overrode by `a:link` on line 317 of style.css look at inspect element in chrome

Comment: what does the !important do? does it like override any other css... ive always wondered...

Comment: well if 2 things are `!important` on one DOM object it waterfalls them as usual css, otherwise it is made dominant